# Using jQuery's .css() for smooth css changes without css-transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to change *smoothly* .css() with jQuery? Like changing .css("top", myValue) from 0 to 200 smoothly by counting up each step (like 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 198, 199, 200)? I do *not* want to use CSS transitions. Reason (long story short): Device which shall run the site does not support transitions smoothly with "top", transformY forces a bug of the browser that's not fixed yet.

Of course I could write a loop like counting "myValue" from 0 to 200 and updating it. But I'd love if there was a jQuery-implemented way.

$("myDiv").css( "top", myValue ); // make it smooth

Comment: I think you are looking for .animate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$.fn.animate` (http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$("myDiv").animate( {top: "+=200"}, duration );
```

(Note: its relative to the current position. so `+=1` is adding 1px and `-=1` is removing 1px.)